# java.io.NotSerializableException even if the class implements “Serializable”

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am getting `java.io.NotSerializableException` even if the class I used implements `Serializable` interface.

I am getting the error as soon as I try to set properties of the object(which is serialized).

What can be the reason for this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that some of the attributes of your class aren't serializable.

Make sure all the attribute classes implement Serializable or use transient to prevent the serialization.

Comment: All the attributes of the classes are also implementing Serializable. Still I am getting the exception.